# Nhibernate search with Lucene.Net, historical data

Tags: nhibernate, lucene.net

When I was searching for SQL full text index solution in Nhinbernate, I came across Lucene.Net solution, and I found and excellent article at http://www.d80.co.uk/post/2011/03/04/Nhibernate-Search-Tutorial-with-LuceneNet-and-NHibernate-30.aspx.

Now I have another question that, I have one existing application and I am migrating it to use Nhibernate. In order to make search function to work properly, I assume need to preload all existing data into Lucene index first.

Since Nhibernate.search is a wrap around Lucene.Net, I think it must have its own document/field convention. So anybody has some best practice or code sample how shall I preload data in database into Lucene index?

Thanks
Hardy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well this is a one-time job really... once you've setup everything run a query for each mapped and indexed class that will fetch all of the results...

```
var allFoo = NHibernateSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(Foo)).List<Foo>();
foreach (var foo in allFoo)
    NHibernateFullTextSession.Index(foo);
```

in the end you can run

```
SearchFactoryImpl sfi = SearchFactoryImpl
                           .GetSearchFactory(new Configuration().Configure());
sfi.Optimize(typeof(Foo));
```